# Yii soap webservice with input parameter

Tags: php, web-services, soap, yii

I need to pass a special unique key (string) in the constructor input of the soap webservice made using Yii framework.
This is example of what I tried:

```
class SoapController extends Controller
{
private $uniqueKey;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->uniqueKey = $_GET['uniquekey'];
}

public function actions()
{
        return array(
                'service'=>array(
                        'class'=>'CWebServiceAction',
                ),
        );
}

/*
 * @return string result
 * @soap
 */
public function actionDemo()
{
    if(isset($this->uniqueKey))
        return $this->uniqueKey;
    else
        return 'key not set';
}
}
```

The wsdl url is:
   ../index.php/soap/service?uniquekey=sss
Which displays the wsdl data in the browser.
But when I call the demo action method (with visual studio for example) I get 'The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.'

at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   ...

The webservice worked before adding the '?uniquekey=sss' part.

Is there another way to pass the $uniqueKey as a parameter for the __construct method, or do I need to customize the actions() method maybe ?
Please, I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can send uniquekey directly as $_GET parameter to function:

index.php?r=SoapController/Show&uniquekey=the_unique_key

Yii Controller:

```
class SoapController extends Controller
{
    public function actionShow($uniquekey)
    {
        //SOAP connect

        $this->render('show',array(
            'soap_data'=>$soap_data,
        ));
    }
}
```

PHP SOAP example:

```
$options = array(
    'exceptions'=>true,
    'trace'=>1,
);

$client = new SoapClient("https://s7sps3apissl.scene7.com/scene7/webservice/IpsApi-2012-02-14.wsdl",$options);

$ns = 'http://www.scene7.com/IpsApi/xsd';

$auth = (object)array(
    'ns2:user' => 'xXx',
    'ns2:password' => 'xXx'
);

$header = new SoapHeader($ns, "authHeader", $auth, false);

$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));

//get company handle
$client->getCompanyInfo(array('companyName' => 'xXx'));

//extract company handle
preg_match('~<companyHandle>(.*?)</companyHandle>~s',$client->__getLastResponse(),$companyHandleMatch);

echo $companyHandleMatch[1];
```